# Using Full Text Search in standarization

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm standardizing street addresses and i think full text search, maybe, work fine with my problem.
My problem is that I have 2 millon of errors and using "LIKE" dont work correctly.
This is what i have now:

```
UPDATE addresses
SET standarAddress = REPLACE (addresses.streetAddress, errors.streetAddress, corrects.streetAddress)
FROM corrects 
INNER JOIN errors 
ON corrects.id = errors.idCorrects
WHERE (addresses.streetAddress LIKE errors.streetAddress + ' ' + '[0-9]%')
```

but instead of LIKE (last line) I want to use this:

```
WHERE CONTAINS(addresses.streetAddress, '@MyErrorVariable')
```

The next is an real example with my tables:

```
--- addresses I want to standarize
CREATE TABLE addresses 
    (id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
     direccion VARCHAR(250))
GO
--- addresses with errors like Acrwod Driv instead of Acrewood Drive
INSERT INTO addresses VALUES (1,'Acrwod Driv 45249')
INSERT INTO addresses VALUES (2,'Advntur Lne 45242')
INSERT INTO addresses VALUES (3,'Aborcrek Lan 45242')
GO
--- corrects street addresses
CREATE TABLE corrects
   (id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    streetAddress VARCHAR(250) NULL)
GO
INSERT INTO corrects VALUES (1,'Acrewood Drive')
INSERT INTO corrects VALUES (2,'Adventure Lane')
INSERT INTO corrects VALUES (3,'Arborcreek Lane')

GO
--- errors form corrects street addresses
CREATE TABLE errors
   (id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    streetAddress VARCHAR(250) NULL,
    idCorrects INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES corrects(id) NOT NULL)
GO
INSERT INTO errors VALUES (1,'Acrwod Driv',1)
INSERT INTO errors VALUES (2,'Advntur Lne',2)
INSERT INTO errors VALUES (3,'Aborcrek Lan',3)
```

My problem with constains is that in this WHERE CONTAINS(addresses.streetAddress, '@MyErrorVariable'), in my @MyErrorVariable only accept value like this 'Acrwod Driv' and all my errors are in errors table. 
Please any idea or help. 
Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide an example where `LIKE` works incorrectly? I think, Full Text Search is not a solution you need.

Comment: Hi! the update that I show work fine with 1000 addresses to standarize, but i have 1 millon and this dont finish never. So, I think that using full text search could work better... Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full text is not going to help as that is a phrase and it would take a while to create the full text index?

Why do you have two tables if you have a one to one relationship on correct to error

```
Fix 
Wrong  PK 
Right    

UPDATE addresses
   SET standarAddress = REPLACE (addresses.streetAddress, Fix.Wrong, Fix.Right)
  FROM addresses
 INNER JOIN Fix
    ON addresses.streetAddress LIKE Fix.Wrong + ' ' + '[0-9]%' 
   and standarAddress <> REPLACE (addresses.streetAddress, Fix.Wrong, Fix.Right)
```

You may want to break it as 2 million is a big transaction log

```
UPDATE addresses
   SET standarAddress = REPLACE (addresses.streetAddress, Fix.Wrong, Fix.Right)
  FROM addresses
 INNER JOIN Fix
    ON addresses.streetAddress LIKE Fix.Wrong + ' ' + '[0-9]%' 
   and standarAddress <> REPLACE (addresses.streetAddress, Fix.Wrong, Fix.Right)
   and Substring(addresses.streetAddress, 0 , 1) = 'a' 
   and Substring(Fix.Wrong, 0 , 1) = 'a'
```

... b
... c 
Substring will use an index

Comment: But, if I use just one table, How would be my registers? corrects and errors in just one table?

Comment: See my answer. It uses one table.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. I want to have just one table with errors and corrects, but i dont know how.Somethign like this? Fields: id (unique)- wrong - right ?

Comment: You say that errors and correct must be just one table? And if is so, how? That is not clear yet. Thanks again!

Comment: OK you can do it as two tables but just let the value be the PK.  What is the purpose to an separate ID to errors if the value must be unique?

Comment: I dont understand how to create "fix" table with wrong and right addresses

Comment: What part of Fix with two columns: Wrong PK, Right is not clear?

Comment: Blam, thanks again for your time. What i dont have clear is that, for example, I have "Acrewood Drive" as right street address and "Acrwod Driv", "Acrwod Drivee", "Acrwoddd Driv" and, 1000 errors or wrong address that are from "Acrewood Drive" as right street. So I dont understand how you say that wrong and right address could in the same "fix" table ? Thanks!

Comment: My answer is a complete answer using a single Fix table.  Apply yourself.

Comment: Wrong PK supports one to many.  I am done trying to help you.

Comment: I really dont understand how you say... but thanks again fro yout time!